# How to check if PHP is running under built-in server?

Tags: php

From PHP, how can I check if my server was started with something like:

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public index.php
```

? I need some special logic to serve static files during development. Nginx won't need this code, so I want to put in a check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling [`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php). It'll return `"cli-server"` when running under the built-in server, and another value (probably `"cgi-fcgi"` or `"fpm-fcgi"`, depending on your setup) when running from nginx.